# Sequence of periodic orbits in a bidimentional vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $X:\Delta\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a vector field and $\gamma\subset\Delta$ a periodic orbit of $X$ with periodicity $\lambda$. 
Let ${\gamma_n}$ a sequence of closed orbits of $X$ with periodicity $\lambda_n$ respectively. 
I must show that there are points $x_n\in\gamma_n$ such that if $x_n\mapsto x$ with $x\in\gamma$, then $\lambda_n\mapsto \lambda$.

I have done this, but I'm not sure of some steps:

Denote $\gamma_n=\psi_n(t,x_n)$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the orbit that passes by $x_n$. So $\psi(t+\lambda_n,x_n)=\psi(t,x_n)$.

I have from hypothesis that $x_n\mapsto x$, so $\psi(0,x_n)\mapsto\psi(0,x)$, which is the same that $\psi(\lambda_n,x_n)\mapsto\psi(\lambda,x)$. So IF we have that $x_n\mapsto x$ implies that $\lim_{n\mapsto\infty}\psi_n=\psi$, then

$\psi(\lambda,x)=\lim_{n\mapsto\infty}\psi(\lambda_n,x_n)=\psi(lim_{n\mapsto\infty},x)$, which is true iff $\lim_{n\mapsto\infty}\lambda_n=\lambda$ by the unicity of the orbit that passes through $x$.

I hope that someone can point out my errors and help me with ideas.